# Setup NGINX as client-side content caching server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, cache-control

I'm trying to setup NGINX as local caching server, to cache all of the web content I load, and then return it back to me, to speed up webpages loading. Official NGINX docs offer `proxy_cache` directive to solve this problem. I set up my server as proxy, by example. Here's my config:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {}
http {
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=1g;
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_cache my_cache;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
            proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502
                              http_503 http_504;
            proxy_cache_background_update on;
            proxy_cache_lock on;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:1416;
        }
    }
}
```

NGINX starts fine with this config, but when I set up a proxy in Firefox to `http://localhost:1416`, it starts saying that proxy server refuses connection. I want to know, what's my misconfigurations there and am I following a right way of setting up NGINX as local client-side caching server?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you have here:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:1416;
```

means that, for each request that matches `location /`, Nginx will proxy it **to** `localhost:1416`. As your `server` block doesn't specify a port, Nginx will listen on the default of 80.

Unless you have something configured elsewhere, nothing is listening on port 1416. You could test this with:

```
curl --proxy http://localhost:1416 http://www.example.com/
```

which will likely fail with:

```
Failed to connect to localhost port 1416: Connection refused
```

While Nginx is often used as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), it is not a good choice for a general purpose caching [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling#Forward_proxies). Consider, for example, [Apache Traffic Server](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/configuration/cache-basics.en.html) or [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).